# Create a private repository on Docker Hub using Docker Registry API Client

Tags: python, docker, dockerhub, docker-image, docker-api

I'm working on a Python 3.6 project in which I need to create a repository on the docker hub account by using API. I have googled a lot but couldn't find any API client to create repositories on docker hub account.

I have found only this module `dockercloud` from [here](https://github.com/docker/python-dockercloud/tree/master) and tried it in this way:

```
dockercloud.user = 'arycloud'
dockercloud.apikey = 'API_KEY'
print(client.Repository.list())
```

But it returns an error like this:

> dockercloud.api.exceptions.AuthError: error getting credentials - err: exec: "docker-credential-osxkeychain": executable file not found in $PATH, out: ``

Is there any way to create a repo on Docker Hub using API?

Answer (score 0):

The [API documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api) does not describe any mechanism for creating repositories on any registry, Docker Hub included.

However, I was able to create a repository using `curl` to send a POST request:

```
TOKEN=$(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username": "'${UNAME}'", "password": "'${UPASS}'"}' https://hub.docker.com/v2/users/login/ | jq -r .token)

curl -s -H "Authorization: JWT ${TOKEN}" "https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/" \
     --data 'description=test' \
     --data 'full_description=full-description' \
     --data 'is_private=false' \
     --data 'name=test' \
     --data "namespace=${UNAME}"
```